# iptables = Packet Flow = Can I savely ACCEPT packets in PREROUTING Chain?

Tags: linux, iptables

I have some "trusted IPs" that I want to allow full access to my machine with "minimal performance impact". The  `PREROUTING -t mangle` is the first chain a packet will pass, entering the system. Is it valid/allowed to use an `-j ACCEPT` in the `PREROUTING -t mangle` Chain??

I am not sure this is allowed, as the PREROUTING chain is before(!!) the internal ROUTING. What happens if I accept a packet in the PREROUTING Chain, will this packet then nevertheless be routed correctly or will -j ACCEPT lead to "bypassing" the Routing?

Answer (score 0):

No. You should setup all allow/denies in your filter chain only. Mangle is meant for altering packets in some way.

You could use mangle to setup a fwmark on the traffic if it matches a series of IP addresses and then permit the traffic via a fwmark instead.

Answer (score 0):

In iptables, `ACCEPT` basically means "done processing this chain, pass the packet to the next chain".

You *don't* have to do anything in the mangle table; the routing *will* happen whether you do something there or not. Well, as long as you don't DROP the packet, of course :)

I think the following page will help you understand. It contains 2 nice diagrams on how a packet traverses the netfilter/iptables chains. The first one is more intuitive, the second is more canonical (but sadly out-of-date):

http://vinojdavis.blogspot.com/2010/04/packet-flow-diagrams.html